# XCode6: Receiving error "Include of non-modular header inside framework module"

Tags: xcode, xcode6, clang, ios-frameworks

I have an iOS app that consists of an app, a bunch of my custom frameworks, and a bunch of third party framweorks:

```
App
    MyFramework1
    MyFramework2
        AFNetworking.framework
        Mantle.framework
        ..
```

I get the error "Include of non-modular header inside framework module"  with the following structure:

```
App/AppDelegate.m
#import <MyFramework2/MyFramework2.h>

MyFramework2/MyFramework2.h
#import "MyClass.h"

MyClass.h
#import <Mantle/Mantle.h>        <-- Error happens here
```

MyFramework2 builds **by itself**.

Trying to build **App** fails with the error "Include of non-modular header inside framework module" *at the line that imports Mantle.h*.

This issue goes away if I import Mantle.h in the `.m` file, but I can't do that because my class inherits from `MTLModel`, which is defined in Mantle.

This issue has been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103169/swift-compiler-error-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module), but it isn't Swift-specific.

Suggestions there are (1) make sure all custom framework headers are public. They are. And (2) go to Build Settings under "Target" and set "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules" to `YES`.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? Is setting "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules" to YES considered a good practice? Why is this an error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Select the .h file in the project navigator. In the target membership area on the right there is a drop down menu next to the target. Select "public" there (probably "project" is selected right now).

[image]

Comment: Note this is a problem even if you have turned on the CLANG setting for "Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules", which your answer solves.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nikos M.  can you please add a screenshot. I cant see that dropdown. Please help. Many thanks

Comment: Where is the dropdown menu for target membership?

Comment: @lenhhoxung it is not a dropdown menu. It's in the right sidebar with the properties.

Comment: @NikosM. Thanks, but it's not applicable for me because the header file is installed via cocoapods

Comment: mine is public and still getting this. :(

Comment: @zaxy78 hey how did you resolved  ? Im facing still same here after making public also..