# Receiving “Include of non-modular header inside framework module” while compiling Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, header

[XCode6: Receiving error "Include of non-modular header inside framework module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552500/xcode6-receiving-error-include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module)

According to this answer, I have to set the "target membership" to "public". However, I can't seem to find this in my inspector.[image]

I've already set the "Allow Non-module Includes in Framework Modules" to "Yes" in my build settings.  I've also added a "Headers" to Build phase (putting the frameworks to "public").  Still has this compile error.

Note: I'm using 4.0.1, and according to changelogs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x) there are no need for bridges anymore...

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix this issue today by downloading v4.4.0, setting "Allow Non-module Includes in Framework Modules" to "No" and removing the includes from my bridging-Header.

[image]

Make sure to add your imports in the class/ViewController that you want to use the Facebook SDK in.

[image]

Comment: Images help greatly with the explanation - Thanks