# “Include of non-modular header inside framework module” while compiling pod

Tags: objective-c, xcode, restkit, cocoapods

I am creating a pod that uses RestKit and a bunch of other pods.

When I am compiling my pod with the command :

```
pod repo push myCocoapodsRepo myPodspec.podspec --allow-warnings --verbose
```

The first error I get is

```
In file included from /var/folders/mx/cg3cmvh14wl2f3mnq0sc_cd00000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/RestKit/Code/ObjectMapping.h:21:
/var/folders/mx/cg3cmvh14wl2f3mnq0sc_cd00000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/RestKit/Code/ObjectMapping/RKObjectMapping.h:23:9: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'RestKit.RKObjectMapping' [-Werror,-Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module]
#import "RKValueTransformers.h"
    ^
```

If I rely on other StackOverflow threads about this error, like

- [Swift compiler error: "non-modular header inside framework module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103169/swift-compiler-error-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module)
- [Include of non-modular header inside framework module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776497/include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module)
- [XCode6: Receiving error "Include of non-modular header inside framework module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552500/xcode6-receiving-error-include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module)

They will all say that setting `CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES` to `YES` and/or placing the problematic header file in the `Public` section instead of the `Project` section, it will solve the problem. But for me, it does not. Those threads also have in common the Swift language, but I do not use it. I'm still using only Objective-C, but I don't know if it has an impact on my problem.

I do not understand what the error means, therefore I have a lot of difficulty solving the problem. Does someone have another solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add the flag **--use-libraries** like this:

```
pod repo push myCocoapodsRepo myPodspec.podspec --allow-warnings --verbose --use-libraries
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It builds now