# FBSDKCoreKit and the include of non-modular header inside framework module errors

Tags: xcode8, cocoapods-1.2

None of the following threads (and many similar) helped me:

[Include of non-modular header inside framework module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776497/include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module)

[XCode6: Receiving error "Include of non-modular header inside framework module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552500/xcode6-receiving-error-include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module)

While trying to install the Facebook SDK in my iOS project via cocoapods, I ran into that error:

Inside the `FBSDKCoreKit.h` header:

```
Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FBSDKCoreKit.FBSDKCoreKit'
```

[image]

As I said, I tried the solutions proposed in the answers above without any success.

It's important to mention that this use to work fine on Xcode 7.

Comment: I have a similar problem and common solutions couldn't help me, how did you solve?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, after upgrade Facebook SDK from 4.38.0 to 5.7.0

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Turn on allowing modular headers

Comment: Not working for me :( keeps throwing the same error

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest version of CocoaPods (1.5.3), the latest Facebook SDK, removing my `Pods` folder, and doing a fresh `pod install` fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just deleted the Swift Package Manager Facebook library and run a `pod update`