# Creating a pod that relies on another pod

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

Trying to build a Cocoapod library which is dependant of other published Cocoapod library I own, got the project in XCode to build OK, but running `pod lib lint` command for checking pod validity fails with 
`error: include of non-modular header inside framework module` on the header files of the library (pod) I'm depending on. All source is Obj-C not Swift.

I did try the following, according to the recommendations found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103169/swift-compiler-error-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module)

- Setting the header files of the dependant library as `public` instead of `project`
- Setting `CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES =
  YES` for each target
- verifying that the relevant headers in build phases are under `public`.

but problem persists, I cannot publish the pod nor test it.

**Update**
when I comment out the 
`s.dependency 'OldPodIDependOn'`
 line in my podspec file of my new pod then error disappears but the dependent headers are not found. if I do not include the pod I depend on in the `Podfile` under the `./Example` folder, like so:

```
target 'NewPod', :exclusive => true do
  pod "NewPod", :path => "../"
  pod "OldPodIDependOn", :path => "../../OldPodIDependOn/"
end
```

then project will just not build in XCode since the `OldPodIDependOn` files are not part of the project. Got a bit of a chicken-or-the-egg problem.

**Update 2**
Also tried removing the `:path => "../../OldPodIDependOn/"` component to reference the pod that has been published instead of a local one - doesn't help.

*Worth mentioning that this pod will include a UI hence a storyboard will be included and referenced, I added `s.resources = 'Pod/Classes/UI/NewPod.storyboard'` line to the podspec file, and removed the storyboard from the pod target compile sources (otherwise xcode won't build). I don't think that this has something to do with the problem but worth mentioning, maybe I'm doing something wrong in there.*

What am I doing wrong?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To finally solve this issue I had to discard the workspace that `pob lib create` created - there was no way around it, I tried all possible combinations / recommendations / code modifications to get rid of the "non-modular header inside framework" errors but nothing seemed to work. `pod lib lint` ALWAYS failed.

I created my own static library xcode project from scratch, then run `pod update` on it after adding the dependent pod to the `Podfile`, then created a `.podspec` file for this lib and added the dependant pod header files to the "Copy files" build phase of the static lib target + `libPods.a` file to the "Link Binary with libs" build phase. Poof! no more "non modular header" errors from `pod lib lint`, even though I am practically doing the exact same thing. Lesson learnt is that `pod lib create` is not recommended for ALL cocoapod cases.

Comment: Actually, the non-modular issue only repos in the dynamic framework when cocoapods building, if you used the libPods.a to import, it exactly didn't.

Comment: With Cocoapod ver 1.10.0 I just did this successfully just by adding the s.dependency in the podspec and not touching the Podfile at all - seems newer versions of Cocoapods handle this gracefully.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and I used

```
pod lib lint MyPod.podspec --allow-warnings --use-libraries
```

When adding the --use-libraries option, it worked.

Comment: Nice shot, I tried a lot of things before this. It works :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

In general `error: include of non-modular header inside framework module` implies that one of the header files inside the resulting framework ( CocoaPods lints for both frameworks and libraries now ) is not stored inside the framework, or classed as a public header.

This can usually be worked around moving external `imports` into the implementation files, see this [Modified to support using framework #353](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/pull/353).

Comment: I removed all includes of headers of OldPod from NewPod headers and moved them in the implementations files. Still won't work. Now two H files of the pod library I am trying to build should in fact be public - so I don't know what you mean when you say 'classed as public header'.

The thing is that the error I am getting is for the building of OldPod (the one  NewPod is dependant on) - though this pod is active and published. Still can't figure it out.. :-/

Comment: is there a way to force `pod lib lint` to build using the "allow non-modular includes in framework modules = YES"? it is set as YES in the XCode project, not sure if this affects pod lib lint

Comment: No, all metadata is kept inside the podspec, any changes in Xcode are not reflected in the Pod. Run with  `--verbose` and you'll see it downloading and creating its own xcodproj.

Comment: You may have to try run your old pod through a `pod lib lint` too, as it may be having trouble being treated as a framework whereas in previous releases it was fine.