# Facebook SDK 4.0.1 Swift Errors xcode 6.2 iOS 8.2

Tags: xcode, facebook, swift, sdk, xcode6

Here in this change-log([facebook change-log](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x)) it is stated that there is no need for objective-c bridging headers for swift.

But when I `import FBSDKCoreKit` in ***AppDelegate.swift*** these errors occur:

**FBSDKAppLinkResolver.h**

> /Users/[username]/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/Headers/FBSDKAppLinkResolver.h:21:9:
> Include of non-modular header inside framework module
> 'FBSDKCoreKit.FBSDKAppLinkResolver'

**AppDelegate.swift**

> /Users/ashrafkholeif/Projects/xcode/TabbedApplicationTemplate/TabbedApplicationTemplate/TabbedApplicationTemplate/AppDelegate.swift:10:8:
> Could not build Objective-C module 'FBSDKCoreKit'

edit: I even set the allow non-modular header inside framework modules to **YES**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the exact same issue, the solution suggested on https://stackoverflow.com/a/29457503/425682 for an Objective-C project worked straight away on my Swift project:

Write a new file in the Facebook SDK folder under Bolts.framework/Modules/module.modulemap with the following content:

```
framework module Bolts {
umbrella header "Bolts.h"

export *
module * { export * }


explicit module BFAppLinkResolver {
    header "BFAppLinkResolver.h"
    link "BFAppLinkResolver"
    export *
}}
```

This works without bridging headers (not needed anymore in version 4.0.1 of the SDK as mentioned by the OP), and without changes to the build settings.

EDIT: this [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/362995353893156) is now fixed as of version 4.1 of the Facebook SDK, the library works without having to do any change.

Comment: This is great! The best solution so far :)
Deleting modules seemed clunky, and messing with clang options did not work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug and Facebook is currently "assigning this to the appropriate team".

To get updates to this issue follow this link:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/362995353893156/

and hit subscribe.

Hopefully it doesn't take them too long to fix.

Also here is a related question recently posted on SO:

[issue using FBSDK in swift iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459073/issue-using-fbsdk-in-swift-ios-application/29472399#29472399)

And some people have found success using the answers on this link (none have worked for me):

[Facebook iOS8 SDK build module error for FBSDKCoreKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435377/facebook-ios8-sdk-build-module-error-for-fbsdkcorekit)

Answer (score 2):

The fix that worked for me:

```
rm -r ~/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/Modules/
```

Repeat with other frameworks.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#xcode_link

Answer (score 1):

Create a new header file and import any objective-c code you are using, something like this..

```
#ifndef RJv1_RJBridge_h
#define RJv1_RJBridge_h
#import "NSMutableString+Obfuscated.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#endif
```

Then go to your Build Settings, look for `Install Objective-C Compability Header`, and make sure is set to `Yes`, then add a relative path to your header file in the field `Objective-C Bridging Header`.

Hope it works!