# issue using FBSDK in swift iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I am coding an iOS 8 app in swift using the FBSDK to allow users to log in to my app. So far I have successfully implemented the login feature using the FBSDK v3.25 in swift using a Bridging-Header.h file and updating the info.plist accordingly to the instructions given on the FB developers website. Now I want to make an app (or update my current one) to FBSDK v4.01 but when I follow the same process of integrating it into my app I get the following errors:

```
-> FBSDKAppLinkResolver.h

    /Users/danieloram/Desktop/IOS/SWIFT/FBLoginUsingSDK4/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/Headers/FBSDKAppLinkResolver.h:21:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FBSDKCoreKit.FBSDKAppLinkResolver'

    /Users/danieloram/Desktop/IOS/SWIFT/FBLoginUsingSDK4/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/Headers/FBSDKAppLinkResolver.h:21:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FBSDKCoreKit.FBSDKAppLinkResolver'

-> Bridging-Header.h

    /Users/danieloram/Desktop/IOS/SWIFT/FBLoginUsingSDK4/FBLoginUsingSDK4/Bridging-Header.h:12:9: Could not build module 'FBSDKCoreKit'

    /Users/danieloram/Desktop/IOS/SWIFT/FBLoginUsingSDK4/FBLoginUsingSDK4/Bridging-Header.h:13:9: Could not build module 'FBSDKLoginKit'

    /Users/danieloram/Desktop/IOS/SWIFT/FBLoginUsingSDK4/FBLoginUsingSDK4/Bridging-Header.h:12:9: Could not build module 'FBSDKCoreKit'

->FBSDKLoginButton.h

    /Users/danieloram/Desktop/IOS/SWIFT/FBLoginUsingSDK4/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/Headers/FBSDKLoginButton.h:21:9: Could not build module 'FBSDKCoreKit'

    Failed to import bridging header '/Users/danieloram/Desktop/IOS/SWIFT/FBLoginUsingSDK4/FBLoginUsingSDK4/Bridging-Header.h'
```

The most obvious thing to note is the last error which says the bridging header cannot be found but it is in the same place as it was for when I was using FBSDK 3.25?

Also, all of the documentation and tutorials on the FaceBook developers website are all in obj-c so finding a solution has been a very frustrating process. Can anyone help diagnose what i am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

*update*

for the time being I have managed to compile my app by following the instructions in the Facebook developers portal and removing all modules from the FBSDK by running the following in terminal

```
rm -r ~/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/Modules/
rm -r ~/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/Modules/
rm -r ~/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKShareKit.framework/Modules/
```

this is my workaround until a proper fix is released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug and Facebook is currently "assigning this to the appropriate team".

To get updates to this issue follow this link:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/362995353893156/

and hit subscribe.

Some people have found success using the answers on this link (none have worked for me):

[Facebook iOS8 SDK build module error for FBSDKCoreKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435377/facebook-ios8-sdk-build-module-error-for-fbsdkcorekit)

Comment: what fixed this issue for me was to Add the "-ObjC" flag to my project's "Other Linker Flags" build setting.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one experiencing this issue! This comes as a great relief to hear its being dealt with

Comment: Just a quick update I was able to get it compiled using abjurato's code form his post on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435377/facebook-ios8-sdk-build-module-error-for-fbsdkcorekit

Answer (score 0):

For those of you trying to compile a swift project with FB cocoaPods.

*BTW, it worked once, only in xCode 7.1 it stopped

Only after playing with everything, I did 2 things:

1. Added the following code at the end of the pod:

   ```
   post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
       configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
   end
   ```

   end
2. Remove the 'new and improved' swift imports, and add FB into the obj-C bridging header:
   [A small screenshot of my bridging header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnK8N.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try with build settings. Set `Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework modules` to `YES`.

Comment: Ah I believe that FaceBook has resolved this issue.. I should update the question!

Comment: Your answer will still be handy for similar situations though!