# React Native fbsdk in iOS

Tags: react-native

When I added fbsdk in my project, I got errors like -

> Warning: Native component for "RCTFBLikeView" does not exist
>   2016-06-21 22:27:38.898 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript]
>
> Warning: Native component for "RCTFBLoginButton" does not exist
>   2016-06-21 22:27:38.899 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript]
>
> Warning: Native component for "RCTFBSendButton" does not exist
>   2016-06-21 22:27:38.900 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript]
>
> Warning: Native component for "RCTFBShareButton" does not exist

To solve this I went through this pod method -
https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/126

Now, when I run `pod install` command, I am getting this error -

> No podspec found for react-native-fbsdkcore in
>   ../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/iOS/RCTFBSDK/core".

Can anybody tall what is wrong here ?

This is my pod file -

```
 platform :ios, ‘7.0’
 use_frameworks!

 xcodeproj ‘/Users/ais/Netizen/ios/Netizen.xcodeproj’

 target ’Netizen’ do
  source ‘https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git’
  pod 'React', :subspecs => ['Core', 'RCTImage', 'RCTNetwork', 'RCTText',      'RCTWebSocket'], :path => '/Users/ais/Netizen/node_modules/react-native'

  pod 'react-native-fbsdkcore', :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native-  fbsdk/iOS/RCTFBSDK/core’
  pod 'react-native-fbsdklogin', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/iOS/RCTFBSDK/login’
  pod 'react-native-fbsdkshare', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/iOS/RCTFBSDK/share’
 end

 target ‘NetizenTests' do

 end
```

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with this recently and what I found to work is that, after running `react-native install react-native-fbsdk` you still need to run `react-native link react-native-fbsdk`.

The libRCTFBSDK.a will then appear under Link Binary with Libraries in Xcode but (I think) needs to be removed and then re-added by clicking the `-` and `+` buttons at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Pod spec support has been removed since a recent version. It expects the FacebookSDK to be ~/Documents directory. See issue here https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/181

Comment: Hi, Thanks. One more thing. If I do these steps in New project, It is working. But, If I follow these steps for my already created project which has other functionalities, it is still showing the same error.

Comment: Even after removing node_modules and reinstalling? Have you removed podspec ?

Answer (score 0):

I have installed react-native-fbsdk and link using react-native-link react-native-fbsdk.

Follow instruction of following link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-ios

This provide to link react-native library using ios_setup.js
There are following step which i have followed.

1. Setup on [facebook developer account](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=ios) .
2. Install the file ios_setup.js by executing the following command in a command prompt at your project's root folder.

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/master/bin/ios_setup.js
```

3. Install the plist package, the xcode package, and the adm-zip package, by executing the following command.

```
npm install plist xcode adm-zip
```

4. Run the script ios_setup.js by executing the following command, and insert your app's App ID and App Name. If the name of your app is more than one word long, then enclose it between quotation marks.

```
node ios_setup.js [App ID] [App Name]
```

When run node ios_setup.js it wll automatically link all files in ios.