# Facebook Native App Login in iOS 9 with Swift & Cocoapods

Tags: swift, cocoapods, facebook-ios-sdk

my problem is as follows:

I would like to use Cocoapods to manage the Facebook iOS SDKs for my swift application.  When installing the latest pods for Facebook, everything works fine.

HOWEVER, those of you who use Facebook SDK might have noticed Facebook has disabled native app login, instead sending users to a safari webview to log in.

As such, I have been trying to use older versions of the Facebook pods to accomplish Facebook login via Facebook the iOS app.

When I attempt to build using pods recommended online (4.5.1), I get the following:

```
'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found
```

Here is my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'
pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.3.4'

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.5.1'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.5.1'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.5.1'

end
```

Has anyone successfully used older Facebook iOS SDK pods with swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h not found error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136279/fbsdkcorekit-fbsdkcorekit-h-not-found-error)

Comment: @RashwanL Not a duplicate, the question linked specifically mentions downloading the SDK and dragging the frameworks into his/her project. 
I am attempting to use Cocoapods for framework management.

Comment: Out of curiosity... Why do you want to avoid using Safari View login? Have you evidence that logins are less successful when using the newer SDK than when using the old one, that does the App Switch?

Comment: @LocoMike In my opinion, the Safari View login completely defeats the purpose of using Facebook Login, which is allowing a user to login without remembering a username/password.  Personally only 1 person I know uses FB via iOS Safari instead of the native app.

Look here for the general reaction from devs, more than one mention backlash from users: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/786729821439894/