# FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h file not found error react-native ios

Tags: react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0, react-native-ios

Try to install Facebook SDK to react natiove IOS.

I have FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h file not found error and spent several hours trying to solve it with different solutions, but can't understand whats going wrong((

Any ideas?

react-native 0.40
react-native-fsdk 0.5.0
facebook sdk: 4.19.0

Comment: You can find solution here with the details; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136279/fbsdkcorekit-fbsdkcorekit-h-not-found-error/48390222#48390222

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136279/fbsdkcorekit-fbsdkcorekit-h-not-found-error)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Check if you did `react-native link` on your RN project.
2. Manually check in *Linked Frameworks And Libraries*, that you have **libRCTFBSDK.a**. If not, hit that + button at the bottom and link it.
3. When upgrading the project itself react-native from <0.40 make sure you ran `react-native upgrade` **after you've updated the RN package itself** with `npm install react-native@latest --save`
4. Make sure that you put sdk in **~/Documents/FacebookSDK**. I think it's important.

If you come across some errors, sometimes it's better to clear all, and start fresh installation again.

Try:

```
rm -rf ./node_modules
watchman watch-dell-all
npm cache clean
npm install
react-native run-ios
```

Comment: Can't believe that putting it in ~/Documents/FacebookSDK fixes the problem for me. I had it in some other directory previously.

Comment: yeah, that fixes. Unbelivable

Comment: How can we use the sdk with SAAS build tools (e.g travis, buddybuild, etc)? Do we have to implement cocoapods in our app todo this? We're currently using carthage

Comment: @Tony. I know that according to FbSDK specification you should put it to the ~/Documents/FacebookSDK. But that is inconvenient because I can't put it on repository. Each developer should have it on ~/Documents/FacebookSDK. So, I've put it on /MyProject/FacebookSDK and I still have this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: for CI or CD see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44236737/facebook-sdk-not-working-if-i-place-the-sdk-folder-inside-react-native-project/45642926#45642926

Comment: dude u saved my day, thanks a lot, putting it in ~/Documents/FacebookSDK fixed the problem. putting it in ~/Documents/FacebookSDK is really really important

Comment: @VarunGupta  but where is Documents folder ?. don't have any document folder in react-native code.

Comment: @Rushitrivedi The Documents folder in the Mac home directory. I don't know about Windows if you are using a Windows laptop.

Answer (score 17):

> EDIT: I recommend using CocoaPods so you don't need to download/update
>   the sdk manually.

---

If you downloaded the sdk manually, try this:

1. Open your `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` folder;
2. Check if it has these cloud icons right of the filenames:

[image: screenshot.png]

If so, macOS removed your files from your computer and uploaded them to iCloud! (thanks Apple)

3. **Click on all the cloud icons, it will download the files back.**

That's it!

---

If this isn't your case, try these:

- Make sure you followed the [getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) correctly;
- Run `sudo chmod -R 755 ~/Documents/FacebookSDK`;
- Try this [troubleshooting](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#33-troubleshooting);
- Try these [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136279/fbsdkcorekit-fbsdkcorekit-h-not-found-error).

Comment: I'm trying to use a CI build tool, however it is going off a combination of npm modules and what's in the github repository (where all of my other frameworks are located). Is it possible to move these sdks into the project structure and change framework search paths etc? It's the only way I can think to allow the build tool to actually build it as it doesn't have access to my documents folder. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Had this problem too but my issue was that `RCTFBSDK` specifically looks in the ~/Documents/FacebookSDK path with a `non-recursive` setting. To check if you have the same problem, open your Libraries folder and `RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj` folder. Check if the Frameworks are red

[image]

If they are, click on them and in the right sidepanel, change the location to where you store the SDK. I store my Facebook SDKs by version number so that was what caused the problem. For example, version 4.12 is stored in `~/Documents/FacebookSDK/4.12`, so `RCTFBSDK` could not find the correct `*.framework`.

Also, click on the `RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj` and add `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` with a `recursive` setting to the Framework Search Paths. It should compile without issues after this.

Comment: Great solution. It is so strange but placing these 3 *.framework documnets into  ~/Documents/FacebookSDK solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

For Xcode 10.x on your main project and on Libraries -> RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj use $(HOME)/Documents/FacebookSDK instead of ~/Documents/FacebookSDK under Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths.

Answer (score 2):

Check the location of your FBSDK file Path. My path ended up being Users/Documents/FacebookSDK

To check go to Library/RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj/Frameworks/

click on one of the frameworks on your file inspector window it shoulw have a section called **Full Path**

Take that path and add it to your Framework Search Paths.

Answer (score 0):

Wile Importing Please make sure the you are **checking** this.

[image]

When you Drag and Drop The Packages.