# Got an Error 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found while integrating facebook in react-native

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on a sample react-native App. In that App I have to integrate facebook module. I followed the steps mentioned from this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/.

While adding the [LoginKit,ShareKit,CoreKit] frameworks into Frameworks folder in Xcode(8.2), I deselected Copy items into destination group's folder and changed Framework Search Path to `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` in Build Settings but I am still facing error:

> 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995528/fbsdkcorekit-fbsdkcorekit-h-file-not-found-error-react-native-ios?rq=1