# Xcode 8 and Swift Could not build Objective C module 'FBSDKLoginKit'

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am having an issue when integrating the latest Facebook SDK 4.16.0 in my Swift 3.0 project using XCode 8. I manually added Facebook SDK to my project
[image]

Framework search paths
[image]

I got a compiling error saying 'Could not build module FBSDKLoginKit'.
[image: Compiling Error]

When I navigate into FBSDKLoginKit.h, an error says 'FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginButton.h' file not found.
[image: File not found]

I searched and found this might relevant [Could not build module 'FBSDKCoreKit' For FacebookSDK 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466683/could-not-build-module-fbsdkcorekit-for-facebooksdk-4) . I tried some approaches, however, it has not worked out.

I'm appreciated your helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. I was able to solve it thanks to [this link](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/). The link was actually useful in completely getting my swift project integrated with the facebook sdk. But because the post might have been a little outdated, I had to do a few things differently. One in particular is my appdelegate. Here's how mine looked when I was done.

```
import UIKit
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
{
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
}
```

So basically following the link would be helpful, but you should make your `appdelegate.swift`, particularly the `application` functions and the `applicationDidBecomeActive` function look as I pasted above.

Also after creating the bridge-header file, adding it to the project build settings looked like this.

[image]

In the link it says it should include the directory of the project like so:
`projectName/Bridging-Header.h` but when I tried that, it seemed it was already looking from my project directory so it ended up looking for my header file at `projectName/projectName/Bridging-Header.h` which is an invalid path. So I added mine like the above screenshot instead.