# 'FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h' file not found (Facebook SDK for iOS v4.2 & Xcode 7)

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I follow all the steps in [This Tutorial](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/) and/or [Facebook SDK Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/)  to install Facebook Login on my App, but when I run the code I get an error. although [Facebook mention I can just use import (Swift)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/#swift) to include the framework, I try to do it the old fashion as well with Objective-C Bridge Header.

**Error:**

> 'FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h' file not found

**Screenshot**
As you can see the bridge.h is being read by the compiler, but due to internal file error it will throw error.
[image]

**Bridge.h** 
 In Xcode 6 you don't require bridge header file, I could just do it with `import`

```
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

This problem is due to Xcode 7 Beta, I have tried to do it on Xcode 6 and it worked perfectly with just an `import FBSDKLoginKit`. Can anyone tell me a hack around this? or if there is a way to convert my Swift 2 code back to 1.4 and work on Xcode 6.

Comment: have you correctly Set “Objective-C Bridging Header” to <#PROJECT_NAME>/Bridging-Header.h  (or whatever name your file have) in your Build phase (swift compiler)? have you tried to change that to just `happens/Bridge.h ?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146677/swift-bridging-header-import-issue

Comment: @mattia As you can see the bridge header is working, but it's not getting the FBSDKLoginKit

Comment: isn't the second compiler error saying "failed to import the bridging header..." ? maybe that's the reason. ;-)

Comment: @mattia due to inside Bridge Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue and recognized, that my old XCode 6 projects worked with the Facebook frameworks.

So i try the following workaround and that fixed the problem. however i don't know why:

Facebook iOS SDK 4.2

1. Create a fresh project in XCode 6
2. Link the Facebook Frameworks to your project as described in the docs
3. Close the project and reopen it in XCode 7
4. The "To Swift 2 Converter" should open within the project - Convert the project to Swift 2
5. Run the project - in my case everything works fine.

After that i copied my "old" Swift 2 Files into the new project. The app starts without any issues.

I observed the changes by the converter, but can't recognized any change depending the Facebook frameworks.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem.

Managed to sort the directory by adding the Facebook SDK in "Framework Search Path".

Target -> Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths -> + /Users//Documents/FacebookSDK

it works!

=]

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot!

Comment: In my case, it was the frameworks search path on the TESTS target that was missing the correct path for the FB SDK header files.

Answer (score 4):

For those using cocoapods the solution for me was actually adding FBSDKCoreKit to podfile:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

[The facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios) is incomplete, they dont mention anything about including `FBSDKCoreKit` pod reference.

Answer (score 2):

For [login,sharekit,corekit].h file not found error , My solution was:

```
changing framework searchpath of RCTFBSDK (inside library of the project)

~/Documents/FacebookSDK
```

to

```
$(HOME)/Documents/FacebookSDK
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, instead of updating the search path
I solved it by removing the Frameworks from the project and then adding them checking the Copy items if needed box

My header files looks this

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` in Framework Search Paths and it will work for any user

Answer (score -1):

this is a known bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/362995353893156/

Check out this solution: [Facebook iOS8 SDK build module error for FBSDKCoreKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435377/facebook-ios8-sdk-build-module-error-for-fbsdkcorekit)

Comment: I have tried every single method writen by people, non of them works

Comment: I believe this have to do something with Xcode 7 Beta Version, Hope this get fixed in stable version. But I'm still trying to find a hack around it.