# facebooksdk.h file not found error in xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa

I just added FacebookSDK.Framework. but in my app delegate i am importing #import. But i got error like this “Facebook/Facebook.h” file not found. But i just drag and drop the facebooksdk framework. But still getting same error. I am also fixing in Build settings (Framework Search Path). still getting same error. I am giving Frameworksearch path like this “/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxxx/FacebookDemo”.  Actually i am following the tutorial.”[How to make Xcode find file FacebookSDK.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849209/how-to-make-xcode-find-file-facebooksdk-h)” But still i got same error. SO Please guide me any body.. i am using xcode7.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745106/fbsdkloginkit-fbsdkloginkit-h-file-not-found-facebook-sdk-for-ios-v4-2-xcod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check where it is downloaded in Downloads or Documents.
next
click on project->targets->framework search path add

$(PROJECT_DIR)/your project name 
also add this

/Users/{username}/Documents/FacebookSDK

FacebookSDK-this should be your downloaded SDK name

Comment: Thanks for your response. but still i got same error

Comment: have u checked with the folder name in Documents and in search path both should be same.

Comment: @Uma this is my FrameworkSearchPath link "/Users/xxxx/Documents/ios-howtos-master/FacebookDemo" and Here ios-howtos-master is my framework name and FacebookDemo is my project name

Comment: 1) $(PROJECT_DIR)/FacebookDemo                                                    2)/Users/{username}/Documents/ios-howtos-master                                           given like only ah?

Comment: @Uma u telugu.. i have one more doubt. i am integrating google plus in my app.. google plus integration successfully done. But problem in my device having google plus app. for example i have login in google plus app in my device. and at the same time i am checking in my application also. but in my application showing login screen only. but i already login in google plus app in my device. so how can i fix the issue??? if you have any idea plz tel me

Comment: @Surya  Google Plus is depreciated right . Use GoogleSignIn so that it will move to Google App.

Comment: @Uma have u stackoverflow account..?? i have some doubts about that one..i need your guidence..

Comment: @Uma i mean chat account

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97634/discussion-between-surya-and-uma).