# I can't figure out how to change my header file to "public"

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, frameworks, header-files

I downloaded the Parse SDK and added all of the dependencies as well as the  Parse.framework and Bolts.framework. Then I went to my app delegate and
started to import Parse and Bolts. Then I got an error saying "Could not build Objective-C module 'Bolts'". This was because of many errors in the Bolts.h file which all said "Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'Bolts'". So after some research I found that people have fixed this error by changing their header file to "public". But when I tried to do this the only options I get in the "target membership" column, after selecting the Bolts.Framework, is to make it required or optional. Why am I not getting the public, private, and project options? What other way can I find those options?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103169/swift-compiler-error-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module 
This was helpful, but I'm not getting those same options.

Comment: I had added Bolts.framework from Facebook SDK and Bolts.framework from Parse SDK. Having both is what caused the problems.
Still I would like to know what other ways I can find the public, private, and project options?

Answer (score 0):

Select the header file in the Project Navigator (right pane of XCode). In the Utilities pane (far right) select the File Inspector tab. Under Target Management you should be able to select the target and change that property.

Incidentally, I had the same issue (both FacebookSDK and Bolts installed). By removing Facebook from Library Search Paths (under Build Settings) I was able to get it working.