# "Include of non-modular header inside framework module" in C header of SSZipArchive

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, swift, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to use [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive) objc library in my Swift iOS Project.

What I did:

1. Created an Objective-C "Cocoa Touch Framework"
2. Followed [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9us3uijFFpo) to import SSZipArchive's objective C and C files into it.
3. Changed all C headers to public as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24317456/1241783)
4. Change build settings to allow non-modular includes as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29672814/1241783)

The framework compiles fine. I'd manage to use objective C libraries in Swift projects using this way before so I guess the steps are correct?

The problem right now is when I try do Import SSZip in my project and try to compile, it gives "Include of non-modular header inside framework module" errors for each of the C header files of SSZipArchive and I've tried all possible solutions I can find online with no success. Seems like the problem centers on zlib.h

[image: Screenshot of compilation error]

Please help.. I'm stuck for more than a week now and I couldn't find any alternatives to unzip a file in swift.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes, let me post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work. You need to move all the #includes that causes problem out from its .h file and put them in its .c file instead. After that clean and recompile and the error goes away and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one more solution how to leave zlib.h import inside headers files and have framework built successfully.

1. Download the source code of zlib from the official site: http://www.zlib.net/ I have used the link: http://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
2. Unzip it.
3. Then add zlib.h and zconf.h headers to your Framework project as well as having libz.tbd linked too.
4. Then set your zlib.h and zconf.h headers public (TARGETS settings -> Build Phases -> Headers)
   [image]
5. Build the project. Everything should be OK.

My Framework works fine after that and successfully unzips files in my iOS app.