# Swift framework: Expose headers from objective-C subproject

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My swift cocoa touch framework contains the subproject, which is an Objective-C static library. (WhirlyGlobe-MaplyComponent).

Now, I wish to expose its classes to my swift code.
If I just add `#include "MaplyComponent.h"` into the umbrella header, I will get `Include of non-modular header inside framework module` even when `Allow Non-modular Includes In The Framework Modules` is set to `YES` in the build settings.

Another way: [Some post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25250520/2380455)
shows how to create a `module.map` file in order to wrap the header into Swift module, I did exactly the same:

```
module MaplyComponent [system] {
    header "/Users/hurden/Developer/repositories/OSMViewer/OSMKit/WhirlyGlobe/WhirlyGlobeSrc/WhirlyGlobe-MaplyComponent/include/MaplyComponent.h"
    export *
}
```

Then `import MaplyComponent` will make everything work, I can call the API, run and test, but Xcode's SourceKitService won't be able to parse the actual headers - no code completion, variable type is `<<error-type>>` and so on, so It seems to me it is not the proper way.

Any suggestions? (There definitely should be the way how I can import the header of the subproject in the umbrella header)

**UPDATE:**
I could resolve an issue with linking the binary distribution instead of the source one. (However it involves horrible header copying from inside of the framework to the project. [Link to original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27810444/2380455).)