# Xcode: LLVM 7.0: Disable warning "Umbrella header for module does not include header"

Tags: xcode, swift, llvm, compiler-warnings

In order for my Objective-C framework to link successfully in my Swift cocoa touch framework, I had to use [this unpretty workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27810444/2380455), which involves importing all framework headers into the project as public headers.

I totally don't need all of them appearing in my umbrella header, so I want to somehow remove the bunch of warnings generated. ("Umbrella header for module 'Foo' does not include header"). I went through LLVM warning settings in the build settings, but could not found it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're getting this warning from a “Compile Swift source files” ▸ “Precompile bridging header” build step (also labeled `PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader`), here's how you suppress it:

1. Find the Build Settings for your project.
2. Search for “Other Swift Flags”.
3. Add `-Xcc` and `-Wno-incomplete-umbrella` to “Other Swift Flags” (in that order).

[image: Xcode build settings]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you explain what `-Xcc` is doing ?

Comment: `-Xcc` tells the `swift` driver to pass the following argument to the C compiler.

Comment: Make sure to put -Xcc BEFORE -Wno-incomplete-umbrella.

Answer (score 3):

The warning flag is [`-Wincomplete-umbrella`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wincomplete-umbrella), so to suppress, pass `-Wno-incomplete-umbrella`.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the header role from public to project and make sure that you don't reference any third-party headers from your own headers - only from implementations.

Any header that is of role public must be imported into the umbrella header.

Comment: the purpose is actually linking against third party framework, the workaround of importing all third-party framework headers as public allows to avoid 'include of non-modular header' linker error, but you don't want to expose these headers, which is why you would just want to ignore the warnings and not include them in umbrella header.