# Include of non-modular header inside framework error with Parse 1.8.2 SDK

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I just updated to the new version of the Parse sdk (1.8.2) and now I cannot compile my project because I get errors saying `Include of non-modular header inside framework`

the error points to the bolts framework that is included inside the Parse framework

```
#import <Bolts/BFTask.h>
```

I already tried setting `Allow Non-modular IncludesIn Framework Modules` to `Yes` but that didnt work

what do I have to do to get rid of this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24103169/4339121

Comment: @soulshined already look at this question and didnt help. I removed the framework and re-added it and set the allow non-modular includes to yes, none of them worked

Comment: Are you developing in Objective-C or in Swift ?

Comment: Did you try going to Build Settings and from there searching for "Allow non-modular includes in Framework modules" and change it to YES

Comment: @JorgeCasariego as you can see in my question I did that