# CocoaPods framework with dependencies - include of non-modular header inside framework module

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I am trying to build a private CocoaPods framework with other pod dependencies.

Among others, I added Parse as a dependency in the podspec file:

```
s.dependency 'Parse'
```

However, when I try to lint it,

```
pod lib lint MyPrivateSpec.podspec  --verbose --sources 'git@bitbucket.org:MY_BITBUCKET_NAME/specs.git,https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'
```

I get the following errors:

> Target Support Files/Parse/Parse-umbrella.h:3:9: note: in file included from Target Support Files/Parse/Parse-umbrella.h:3:
>
> ERROR | xcodebuild:  Parse/Parse/Parse.h:12:9: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'Parse.Parse'
>
> [and more of these types of errors in the following lines ...]

I looked at virtually every relevant question asked on SO and in github issues, but I could not find anything that worked for me. Has anybody experienced these issues, or is familiar with why this does not work ?

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately a problem with the Parse library itself. I ran into a similar situation a while back when I was trying to use the Parse library inside a framework I was building for iOS.

What the error means is that there is a header included in one of Parse's public .h files that does not belong to a module. In Parse's case this is `<sqlite3.h>` if I remember correctly. Without removing this from Parse's public headers it will not be possible to build a framework target that also includes Parse. This should be filed as a bug with Parse so they could work on an upgrade to support modular framework builds.

Due to the need for my project to build a framework target I had to pass on using Parse in my project as a result of the above.

Here is a reference to a similar problem with similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24728646/296708

Comment: It seems that `sqlite3.h` is not in Parse's public `.h` files anymore, but the problem is still there. `Searching for "sqlite3.h"
 in .

./Pods/Parse/Parse/Internal/LocalDataStore/SQLite/PFSQLiteDatabase.m:13:#import <sqlite3.h>
./Pods/Parse/Parse/Internal/LocalDataStore/SQLite/PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.m:12:#import <sqlite3.h>
./Pods/Parse/Parse/Internal/LocalDataStore/SQLite/PFSQLiteStatement.m:12:#import <sqlite3.h>
./Pods/Parse/Parse/Internal/PFDateFormatter.m:12:#import <sqlite3.h>`

Comment: Good to know. Then I'm guessing that there may still be another Objective-C or C library being included in one of Parse's .h header files that is still causing the "include of non-modular header" error if you are still seeing this error.

Comment: Yes, and since it can be reproduced by starting from `pod lib create xxx`, I've created an issue in github for Parse's reference: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/673

Comment: really helpful answer save my time