# Include of non-modular header inside framework error - how do you make transitive dependencies work with cocoapods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, dependency-management, ios-frameworks

I have created an open source library (https://github.com/linkedin/LayoutTest-iOS) which has two Cocoapods inside - LayoutTest and LayoutTestBase. LayoutTest depends on LayoutTestBase and one of the .h files needs to import something from LayoutTestBase. Currently, I do this using:

```
@import LayoutTestBase;
```

However, this only works if the application uses `use_frameworks!` in their Podfile. Some apps do not want to use this cocoapods option. Without `use_frameworks!`, it works if I use:

```
#import <LayoutTestBase/LYTLayoutPropertyTester.h> // OR
#import "LYTLayoutPropertyTester.h"
```

However, when using this with `use_frameworks!`, it gives the error: "Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'LayoutTest.LYTLayoutTestCase'"

Clearly, there should be a way of doing this import regardless of whether the user uses `use_frameworks!` or not in their Podfile. How can I get this library to compile and run correctly?

**Research**

I've looked on stackoverflow, and this seems to be the most similar question:
[CocoaPods framework with dependencies - include of non-modular header inside framework module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33261967/cocoapods-framework-with-dependencies-include-of-non-modular-header-inside-fra). It mentions that it's a problem with the Parse library, but doesn't mention how it needs to be fixed. Since I own the dependency, I can fix this.
I've also tried setting Allow non-modular frameworks to YES in all settings (projects, unit tests, all pods, etc), and this doesn't seem to do anything.

**To Reproduce**

Create a new project. Add this Podfile:

```
target :'{MyAppTarget}Tests' do
pod 'LayoutTest'
end
```

Run `pod install`. Try to run unit tests on the app. It will fail. Now, try changing LYTLayoutTestCase.h to use `#import <LayoutTestBase/LYTLayoutPropertyTester.h>`. It now works. However, if you add `use_frameworks!` to the Podfile, it no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the optimal solution but the work around I found was to do an `#if __has_include` and do both solutions depending on whether it was built with `use_frameworks!`

Here's a link to the github issue with more details: https://github.com/linkedin/LayoutTest-iOS/issues/8

If anyone knows how libraries like parse-SDK do it without these workarounds, I'm still interested.