# Linking against iOS Framework that uses zlib

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7, zlib

I'm helping a consumer of my [UnzipKit](https://github.com/abbeycode/UnzipKit) library, who's having problems linking the framework from his iOS-Swift framework target. UnzipKit uses MiniZip, whose `unzip.h` and `ioapi.h` headers include `zlib.h`. Those include lines are failing with this message:

```
Include of non-modular header inside framework module UnzipKit.<ioapi or unzip>
```

I realize that Xcode 7 is now using `tbd` libraries instead of `dylib`, but I've tried each of the following with each combination of source and target framework, and still get the errors:

1. Replacing the `libz.dylib` reference with `libz.tbd`
2. Removing all framework links with a `-lz` Other Linker Flag
3. Creating a framework link to `/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib`
4. Toggled the **Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules** setting to Yes and No

He posted a sample project [on GitHub](https://github.com/iblacksun/UnzipKitIssue.git). To reproduce:

1. Checkout the project
2. Install [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) if you don't have it already:

   ```
   brew update
   brew install carthage
   ```
3. Run `carthage update` in the checkout directory
4. Open UnzipKitIssue.xcodeproj and build the **UsingUnzipKit** scheme

Comment: Take a look at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24103169/1180620).

Comment: @MarkAdler Thanks, I updated my question to mention I tried the "Allow Non-modular Includes" setting. Most of the answers were restating that solution. Regarding the rest, the `zlib.h` header is outside my project (so I can't make it public), and it didn't seem like a good idea to move the includes of `zlib.h` into the .m files – I try to keep MiniZip as close to the original version as possible.