# use masonry in swift and objectiveC mix project

Tags: swift, masonry-ios-osx

I have a objective-C and Swift mix project. I m using Masonry library for autolayout. I m able to use masonry in Objective C code but not in swift. How to do that  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create [bridging header file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37291394/1244597) if you haven't yet, and paste following line

```
#import "Masonry.h"
```

If you are using CocoaPods to add Masonry to your project, you might see error `Masonry.h file not found`, this is because you need to set `User Header Search Paths`, to do so goto `TARGETS > Build Settings` and paste following

```
//:configuration = Debug
USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = pods/**

//:configuration = Release
USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = pods/**

//:completeSettings = some
USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS
```

Screenshot to make sure `User Header Search Paths` is properly set

[image]

***Note*** After setting above header, you do not need `import Masonry` line in your swift file

Usage

```
UIView.mas_makeConstraints { (make:MASConstraintMaker!) in
    make.centerY.mas_equalTo()(anotherView)
    make.left.mas_equalTo()(15)
    make.height.mas_equalTo()(30)
    make.width.mas_equalTo()(30)
}
```