# Include of non-modular header inside framework module error

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, parse-server

Trying to integrate **ParseLiveQuery** cocoapod into my project, but when building I keep getting the error:

> Include of non-modular header inside framework module error
>   'Bolt.BFCancellation'

[image]

I installed **ParseLiveQuery** (along with Parse) via cocoapods. Here's my podfile:

```
use_frameworks!

pod 'ParseLiveQuery'
pod 'Parse'

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
    configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
  end
end
```

I have also set **Allow Non-module Includes In Framework Modules** to **Yes** in build settings, but still get this error.

Answer (score 9):

Just ran into this myself.  I added the header file to the Framework's umbrella header, and then added it to the Headers section as Public.  (I'm adding Reachability lib)

[image]

So far it seems to be working for me without trouble.

Comment: In that case, the Reachability will be visible outside of the framework. But I don'' want these Reachability class to be exposed, what should I do? –

Comment: I'd have to think about it a bit, but does it really matter?  Reachability is a "public" library, so what is the downside of having it "available" via your library?

Comment: Yes, it does matter. Since there are lots of OC codes in my framework. I don't want the users of my framework to see these OC codes. Anyway, I found an another solution: using module like this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085217/swift-project-missing-required-modules-when-import-a-modular-framework

Comment: @DàChún [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37072619) basically says to make a separate swift module for the Obective-C code so that the headers don’t have to be set as `Public`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it removing `Modules` folder from the framework.

- Browse to your framework location which is present in the App Project using finder
- Go inside `Test.framework` folder (In the above case it will be `ParseLiveQuery.framework`) & Delete `Modules` folder.
- Clean and Re Build the app, it will solve the problem.