# Starscream: Updating pod create compilation error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, starscream

I have installed `Crashlytics`using pod.

```
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

But after updating the pod file `Starscream 1.1.4 (was 1.1.1)` also get updated. Now build the project shows me following error

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me how to solve it? Any idea?

> UPDATE

I did as @Ivan said then I am getting the following error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Starscream pod has been updated for Swift 3 now, so when you install new pods, it has been also updated to new version for Swift 3.

If you don't want to update Starscream, you need to keep pod lock file generated when you install pod at the first time. It should fix your pod versions as it was.

If you did update pod (not just install), lock file never work for you.

Cheers

Comment: I did but now some other problem arise.

Comment: So what did you do exactly?

Comment: I use pod install

Comment: could you delete pod lock file and reinstall from scratch?

Comment: and then if you meet syntax errors related with swift 3, you need to fix them manually. or you can refer this thread:https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4420 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103169/swift-compiler-error-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module