# add module into ios framework, app get "module not found"

Tags: ios, swift, module, frameworks

I have a swift framework project(let's call it Framework1), inside it use some 3rd party objective c files. I use module instead of umbrella file because of ambientlight's answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103169/swift-compiler-error-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module)

I create a subfolder(let's call it MiscModule), put module.modulemap under that folder, include all oc headers, and configure the Build Setting. The framework build fine, I can get framework build.

But after I put Framework1 in app project, build the app. It complain about "Module MisModule not found".

I saw the Framework1-swift.h file have an line of "@import MisModule". I had thought MisModule is build into binary in Framework1's bundle.

Do I miss something?

Comment: I've the same problem, did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

When you built it, those files that in modules did not be embedded into the framework, it would change the relative path to absolute path.

such as `import YourModule` change `$SRCROOT/...` to `User/YourProject/`

so, not use custom module in framework, it will change the `import paths` to
absolute path.

Your can build a framework for the oc files.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes cleaning Xcode, restarting both the simulator and xcode, and then trying to run again helps. If worst comes to worst, try heading into finder and doing a deep-clean. `Delete ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

Comment: I did clean up, rebuild everything, still get the same problem