# FirebaseAdMobPlugin.h file not found when using firebase_admob Plugin for Flutter

Tags: flutter

I can't build on `iOS` Simulator when using `firebase_admob` Plugin.
I can build on `Android`.

console log:

```
=== BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
/Users/rkowase/StudioProjects/stopwatch/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: fatal error: 'firebase_admob/FirebaseAdMobPlugin.h' file not found
#import <firebase_admob/FirebaseAdMobPlugin.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
    Could not build the application for the simulator.
    Error launching application on iPhone X.
```

flutter doctor

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.1.5, on Mac OS X 10.12.6 16G1114, locale en-JP)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
[✓] Connected devices (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_admob:
```

I use firebase_admob v0.5.0
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_admob

Sample code
https://github.com/rkowase/flutter-firebase-admob-sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103169/swift-compiler-error-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module/24317456#24317456) workaround.

### Links

"Made Podfiles use symlinks to local pods" not working · Issue #15099 · flutter/flutter
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15099

objective c - Swift compiler error: "non-modular header inside framework module" - Stack Overflow
[Swift compiler error: "non-modular header inside framework module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103169/swift-compiler-error-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module/24317456#24317456)

PathProvider not found on iOS build - Google Groups
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/flutter-dev/7QRk1RphLDE/5rLS4CciBwAJ