# Include of non-modular header inside framework module - Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-analytics, ios-frameworks

When I tried to install the google analytics using the pod in my framework, the pod is successfully added to my framework project. But when I tried to import the `#import <Google/Analytics.h>`in my framework umbrella header I got this error. I am using Xcode 9.2 and my framework built in swift.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift compiler error: "non-modular header inside framework module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103169/swift-compiler-error-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module)

Comment: No, I have checked that there is no duplicate file exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, select the GoogleAnalytics SDK folder and drag and drop inside the framework app. Then add all the .h file as a public in Build Phases-> Headers-> public.

And also you need to add the below supporting framework in General ->

```
Embedded Binaries:
SystemConfiguration.framework
CoreData.framework
ImageIO.framework
libz.tbd
libsqlite3.tbd
libGoogleAnalytics.a
```

Cleaned and run build your framework project and it will run successfully.